# Traverse Non-Binary Tree

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to traverse a non-binary tree. A string representation of the tree, as a `list`, is:

> ['TOP', ['S', ['NP', ['PRP', 'I']], ['VP', ['VBP', 'need'], ['NP',
>   ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'flight']], ['PP', ['IN', 'from'], ['NP',
>   ['NNP', 'Atlanta']]], ['PP', ['TO', 'to'], ['NP', ['NP', ['NNP',
>   'Charlotte']], ['NP', ['NNP', 'North'], ['NNP', 'Carolina']]]], ['NP',
>   ['JJ', 'next'], ['NNP', 'Monday']]]]]]

This is from the [Penn Treebank](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/). Ultimately, I'd like to turn this into a binary tree, but first I need a way to traverse the tree, as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def traverse(tree_of_lists):
    for item in tree_of_lists:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for x in traverse(item):
                yield x
        else:
            yield item
```

This is the "basic" solution -- can run in Python 2.7 and gives you an iterable that you can simply loop on.  (In recent Python 3.* versions you'd use `yield from item` instead of the inner `for` loop).

The `isinstance` test is unpleasant but depending on your exact problem it may be the only way to distinguish a "scalar item" from a "sub-tree".  There may be better ones but you don't give us enough information to be able to tell.  For example, if all "leaves" (scalars) are strings, you might prefer to check for that (still an `isinstance` check, alas!).

Comment: What do you mean by a "scalar item"?

Comment: @Adam_G a single value, not a list.

Comment: Also known as "a leaf", that would be whatever represents other than a "sub-tree" in your apparent representation of a tree (looks like all your sub-trees are lists and all your leaves/scalars are strings, but that's just inferred from that one example, thus, a bit fragile, missing a clearly declared specification).

Comment: You are correct. Since this is a representation of a sentence, the lowest level would be a word.

Comment: Is there a way to print these results?

Comment: @Adam_G, sure -- e.g `for x in traverse(tree): print(x)` -- and many, many others.

Answer (score -3):

There are many ways to traverse a tree.  Options include:

- pre-order traversal — Emit the current node, then recursively traverse its children
- post-order traversal — Recursively traverse the current node, then emit the current node
- in-order traversal — Recursively traverse the left child.  Then emit the current node.  Finally, traverse the right child.  Implies a binary tree, but it can be adapted to a general tree if you have some way to split the children into "left" and "right" groups.

You could "emit" a node by appending it to an accumulation list, but a better way would be to use a generator and `yield` the nodes.

You'll find these and other options on [Wikipedia page on tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).  Pick one that meets your need.

Comment: Well, it's a pretty basic question that a quick Google can easily find.  Also, there are many ways to traverse a tree, and the question provides no indication on which method is desired.